# Number equations in Word - give one number to two equations

Tags: microsoft-word, latex, equations

How can I number equations in word, similar to how it is done in Latex?

If I have just one equation on a line, I usually type the number to the right of it, for example: `y = x+1 (3)`. But I have a situation with 2 lines of equations, one under the other, that I would like to label with a single number. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you need something that *translates easily* into Latex (can't help with that) or *looks OK* when printed/PDF'd from Word, but if you have this

```
a + b = c

d + e = f
```

and you want those two equations to be have a single number that is aligned vertically, something like this:

```
a + b = c
            (15)
d + e = f
```

then there are a few things you could do, e.g.

Actually insert a paragraph between the two equations and put the equation number on that line, using manual tabbing or normal Word alignment features to place the number horizontally.

Put the equations in a 2-column or 3-column table (2-column with the equation in column 1 if you want to left-align your equations, 3-column with the equation in column 2 if you want to centre-align them). Merge the cells in the last column, put the equation number in there and align it vertically. This is I think the same approach as proposed by @wordexperto.com .

Combine the two equations into a single equation using an \eqarray construct and place the number after your equation in the way you are already doing.

As an example of the latter, instead of two separate equations like this:

```
a + b = c
d + e + f = g
```

You enter the following text in the equation editor

```
\eqarray(&a+b=c@&d+e+f=g)
```

You may already know how Equation Arrays work, but if not, the `@` charater indicates a new row, and when you have multiple `&` characters in a row, they alternate between being *alignment points* and *spacers*. So in this case the `&` characters are there to left-align the two equations, whereas

```
\eqarray(a+b&=c@d+e+f&=g)
```

If you put your equation number at the end of this, e.g.

```
\eqarray(a+b&=c@d+e+f&=g) (15)
```

it should be aligned vertically 'between' the equations. But that will probably only look OK if the two equations have equal or similar height.

If you already have two equations that use `\eqarray` or `\matrix`, you should still be able to wrap them in an outer `\eqarray`.

As others have mentioned, you can use `{ SEQ }` fields to number your equations automatically if you wish. Using them *inside* an equation does work but I have found that it is rather easy to delete things accidentally when working with equations, so proceed with caution.

Incidentally, for some time now it has been possible to add a # character at the end of your equation text, followed by the numbering you want, and the equation editor will right-align that number automatically. e.g.

```
\eqarray(&a+b=c@&d+e+f=g)#(15)
```

THis will also work with a `{ SEQ }` field instead of the `15`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the equations.

[image]

2. Go to References -> Insert caption. Click on `New Label`. Type `(`. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. A number will be insterted on the Caption box. Type `)`. By default the numbering format will be `1,2,3...`. You can change it by clicking on `Numbering`.

[image]

3. The number will be insterted on the left. Click Home, then on the Paragraph section, select `Align Right`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However if I do that the numbering is placed below the equations. I would like to place it to the right of them, but at the same level with them, as it is done in Latex (I am submitting a paper to a Journal and they required to use Word as the text editor, so I would like to have a similar formatting to the one in Latex).

Answer (score 0):

I explain it in these posts and videos on my blog:

https://wordexperto.com/2016/02/04/numerar-ecuaciones-numbering-equations-2/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaG4w9Zukxw&list=PLF1OL9sNXkSxCXoA2XS6tNtpPPXJhjuB7&index=7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: First link is Spanish.